# Material design toolbar - Margin left on title when no icon

Tags: material-design

In the material design guidelines I can't find how much should the left margin be for the title, when there is no "nav icon" (as it is called in guideline).

We see here:

https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

There is always a nav icon, the three stripe menu icon. When this is present we have a margin left of 72dp.

How about when it is not present?

Is there a better guideline with more detailed margins/padding for material guidelines? Stuff is missing like the above case, and the dimensions of icons, and font size, elevation, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is no Hamburger menu icon, **The title is shifted to its place**. This is how it is seen in many material design apps.

### Whatsapp:

[image]

### Messages:

[image]

---

> Is there a better guideline with more detailed margins/padding for material guidelines? Stuff is missing like the above case, and the dimensions of icons, and font size, elevation, etc.

I dont think there is a better guide to material design than [material.io](http://material.io). If you want more references or guides regarding this, please raise a question or check if anything exists in [graphic design stackexchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).